# Automorphisms of manifolds sending one set of points to another

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

> Let $M$ be a manifold and let $Q_n,P_n \subset M$ be sets of
> cardinality $n$, then we can always find an automorphism of $M$,
> sending $Q_n$ to $P_n$.

I've read this statement in a lecture script of a friend, but am quite sceptical if this is true, or if it needs some restrictions.

For connected manifolds it can be easily shown by proofing that the set of points, for which we get such an autom. is both closed and open in $\prod_{i=1}^nM$ (it isn't empty, bc of the identity map).

If the manifold $M$ is not connected, couldn't we just consider $M=S^1\dot\cup (0,1)$ with one point in $S^1$ and another one in $(0,1)$, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Any diffeomorphism (or homeomorphism) of $M$ induces a bijection between its components and since the components $S^1$ and $(0,1)$ are not homeomorphic, $S^1$ has to be sent to $S^1$ and $(0,1)$ has to be sent to $(0,1)$. So no automorphism of $M$ can take points from one of these components to the other.